# Pop Alert will change view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I have this function and I use it on almost all viewController´s that I have, for some reason went I push "ok" to dismiss the pop up, it switches to another viewController.

this is my function...

```
extension UIViewController
{

    func displayAlert(title: String, message: String)
    {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

        alert.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler:
            { (action) -> Void in
                self .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })))

        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

any help? I'm using Xcode 7.0 beta 6 with swift 2

Comment: instead of `self .dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)` try `alert.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)`. `self` may be referring your view controller here

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to dismiss the alert controller yourself. That happens automatically with your alert action. You're simply providing a closure that gets called when that "OK" action gets triggered. Just remove this line:

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```